# Sort data in an ascending order based on the geometry of an sf object in R (Sort by Lat/Long)

Tags: r, sf, sorting, order

I am trying to sort my data based on the latitude and longitude. I have an `sf` object in R, which essentially stores the latitude and longitude as a separate column called geometry.

See below:

```
> head(barfly.pr.sp)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 14 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 76.99832 ymin: 10.04038 xmax: 77.0799 ymax: 10.1619
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

    effort_distance_km effort_area_ha reviewed                  geometry
0                 0.00              0    FALSE  POINT (77.0351 10.14666)
0.1              24.14              0    FALSE   POINT (77.066 10.08324)
0.2               8.00              0    FALSE POINT (77.05931 10.09309)
0.3               3.00              0    FALSE  POINT (77.0799 10.04038)
0.4               1.20              0    FALSE  POINT (76.99832 10.1619)
0.5               2.50              0    FALSE POINT (77.06757 10.15112)
```

I am trying to sort the same based on geometry and I get this error:

```
> barfly.pr.sp <-  barfly.pr.sp[order(barfly.pr.sp$geometry),]
Error in Ops.sfc(xi, xj) : operation > not supported
```

I also tried `dplyr::group_by()` and I got the following error:

```
barfly.pr.sp <-  barfly.pr.sp %>% group_by(geometry)
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `geometry` can't be used as a grouping variable because it's a sfc_POINT/sfc
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mutate your data with temporary values. Create new objects with temporary values. Here's a solution that does not mutate the original data in any way apart from the ordering, and also only uses base R operations:

```
nc <- st_read(system.file(package = "sf", "shape/nc.shp"))
xy = st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc))
```

Now sort by X coord first and use Y to break ties (which are probably unlikely for polygon centroids, but might happen with discrete point data).

```
nc.sort = nc[order(xy[,"X"], xy[,"Y"]),]
```

As a test, check that the difference in successive X coordinates is now non-negative:

```
> range(diff(st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc.sort))[,1]))
[1] 0.001191683 0.282903325
```

Compare with original which was not in increasing X coordinates:

```
> range(diff(st_coordinates(st_centroid(nc))[,1]))
[1] -7.290978  7.171192
```

Answer (score 3):

I was just about to answer when jsta posted. I will post an alternative solution anyways that is a bit less code, sorts on x and y and removes x and y when finished:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file(package = "sf", "shape/nc.shp"))
nc <- st_centroid(nc)

nc.sort <- nc %>% cbind(st_coordinates(.)) %>%
  arrange(X, Y) %>%
  select(-X, -Y)
```

Comment: Why would you risk mutating the object twice (first adding the columns and then removing them) if you can use simple indices and not mess with your data?

Comment: good point. Spacedman's answer is better